# Laravel Form Model Binding One to One Relationships Not Populated

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Terms table:

- term_id
- name
- slug

Term_taxonomy table:

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- description

My Term model:

```
public function TermTaxonomy(){
    return $this->hasOne('TermTaxonomy');
}
```

My TermTaxonomy model:

```
public function Term(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Term');
}
```

my Controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
    $categories = Term::with(['TermTaxonomy' => function($q){
        $q->select('term_id', 'description');
    }])->get(['term_id', 'name', 'slug']);

    $category = Term::with(['TermTaxonomy' => function($q){
        $q->select('term_id', 'description');
    }])->find($id, ['term_id', 'name', 'slug']);
    return View::make('qhymchildz.backend.posts.categories', compact('category', 'categories'));
}
```

My View

```
        @if (isset($category))
        {{ Form::model($category, ['route' => ['admin_posts_categories_update', $category->term_id], 'method' => 'PATCH']) }}
    @else
        {{ Form::open(['route' => 'admin_posts_categories_store'])}}
    @endif 

        {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
        <span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip radius" title="Category name for your posts.">
        {{ Form::text('name', '', ['placeholder' => 'Category name here']) }}
        @if ($errors->has('name')) <small class="error"> {{ $errors->first('name') }} </small> @endif
        </span>

        {{ Form::label('slug', 'Slug') }}
         <span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip radius" title="Slug or URL for your category.">
        {{ Form::text('slug', '', ['placeholder' => 'Slug here']) }}
        @if ($errors->has('slug')) <small class="error"> {{ $errors->first('slug') }} </small> @endif
        </span>

        {{ Form::label('description', 'Description') }}
        {{ Form::textarea('description', '', ['placeholder' => 'Category description here', 'size' => '50x5']) }}

    @if (!isset($category))        
        {{ Form::submit('Add New Category', ['class' => 'radius button']) }}
    @else
        {{ Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'radius button']) }}
    @endif

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

and all input text is not populated, already try many way from googling but nothing work, then how to populate data in my input text and text area ? i use it for edit function.

Thanks, i am new in laravel. any help will be appreaciated.

Comment: Try passing `null` instead of an empty string as value: `{{ Form::text('name', null, [...]) }}`

Comment: nice too meet you again @lukasgeiter now name and slug input text populated , but description still blank, because it in one to one relationships and different table. already try many why but not working. then how to populate description ?. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the second parameter has to be `null` so it will actually use the value from your model:

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['placeholder' => 'Category name here']) }}
```

To use a property from a related model you can use this:

```
{{ Form::textarea('TermTaxonomy[description]', null, ['placeholder' => 'Category description here', 'size' => '50x5']) }}
```

**Note** that there's no need to do an `@if(isset($category))` at the beginning. The `Form::model` method will handle non-existent models on it's own. This is sufficient:

```
{{ Form::model($category, ['route' => ['admin_posts_categories_update', $category->term_id], 'method' => 'PATCH']) }}
```

Comment: yeah it work to show description but when i try to add new category , iget undefined index: description and point to this line `$TermTaxonomy->description = $data['description'];` then i change to `$TermTaxonomy->description = $data['TermTaxonomy']['description'];` and its work, is this correct way ? after i remove `isset()` it show form correctly and update button and save button correctly how this can be done ? since i remove `isset()` as i know to detect is update or add new we need to use if , if edit then show edit form and update button else add new form and add new button @lukasgeiter

Comment: Yes accessing it like you described is correct. Also you will still need the isset() for the submit button

Comment: i dont use isset() in submit button , but it works like expected dont know why. @lukasgeiter

Answer (score 1):

In my case was not rendering the model value on the Textarea.

So instead of null i give the value like this:

```
{{ Form::textarea('TermTaxonomy[description]', $category->TermTaxonomy['description'], ['placeholder' => 'Category description here', 'size' => '50x5']) }}
```

Hope this also helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, but I did it like this:

```
{!! Form::text('firstname', $user->profile->firstname, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

In my case:
User `belongsTo('App\Profile')`,
Profile `hasOne('App\profile')`

Just get an idea. Hope it helps!